# Implementing RESTful service and consume xml at the service and map it to a bean class

Tags: web-services, rest, resteasy, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

Can anyone please explain hot to implement RESTful service and post data in an xml and cnsume the xml at the service and map it to a java bean class? It would be better if an example can be posted.   I have tried it using a json object using this 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-resteasy-client-framework/
  but not able to do it with an xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same site that you tried the json example also provides a [RESTEasy + JAXB example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-xml-file-from-jax-rs-with-jaxb-resteasy/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your REST methods:

`@Consumes("application/xml")` and `@Produces("application/xml")`. Your method would consume/produce XML.